# Selected index on the "more" view of a UITabbar

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

How can I manage the user selection on the "more" view of a UITabBar? I have this code to manage the UITabBarItems selections:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {    
    if (!(viewController == tabBarController.moreNavigationController)) {
        int index = tabBarController.selectedIndex;
        [[DataManager sharedInstance] setCurrentTabbarIndex:index];
    }
}
```

It works fine for the visible UITabBarItems, but when the user select some item from the "more" view I never get informed about that. Is there some way to catch the user item selection of the "more" view? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "more" view of a UITabBarController is handled separately from the other views.  Apple's discussion on this subject says the following:

> [The 'moreNavigationController'] property always contains a valid More navigation controller, even if a More button is not displayed on the screen. *You can use the value of this property to select the More navigation controller in the tab bar interface or to compare it against the currently selected view controller*.
>
> Do not add the object stored in this property to your tab bar interface manually. The More controller is displayed automatically by the tab bar controller as it is needed. You must also not look for the More navigation controller in the array of view controllers stored in the viewControllers property. The tab bar controller does not include the More navigation controller in that array of objects.

Judging from that I would think that you can do something like:

```
int index = tabBarController.selectedIndex;
if (tabBarController.selectedViewController == 
    tabBarController.moreNavigationController) {
    index = -1;  //assign some placeholder index for the "More" controller
}
```

Comment: The more view controller has a UITableView, I need to execute some code when some of the cell is touched. In others words, I need to manage the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method for the UITableView that the "more view controller" haves. Don't you know if there is some way to do that?

Comment: Ah, I don't know if you can do that directly.  Perhaps you could subclass UITabBarController and provide an implementation that uses a custom "more" view controller that lets you handle the row selection.  Or maybe a simpler option is to move the `[[DataManager sharedInstance] setCurrentTabbarIndex:index];` call to your view controllers' `viewWillAppear` methods.

Comment: I have search a lot and I don't have the solution yet. I can't move [[DataManager sharedInstance] setCurrentTabbarIndex:index]; to the viewDidLoad because the view needs to be configured in relationship with the selected item on the UITabBar. Anyway, I will think in some other solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

A very late answer for a very old question, but here it is anyway, in case someone stumbles upon this.

The solution is to assign yourself as the delegate of the "more" navigation controller. You already have a class that adopts the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol, so the .h file might look like this:

```
@interface MyDelegate : NSObject <UITabBarControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
}
```

Wherever you are assigning your class as delegate, do this:

```
- (void) assignDelegate:(MyDelegate)myDelegate toTabBarController:(UITabBarController*)tabBarController
{
  tabBarController.delegate = myDelegate;
  tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = myDelegate;
}
```

And finally, in your delegate class add this method:

```
- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController*)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     // add code to handle the event
}
```

Note that none of your delegate methods are invoked when you change tabs programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach I've found for this problem is to become the delegate for the UITableView which is the topViewController in the UITabBarController.moreViewController.
Implementing the didSelectRowAtIndexPath should solve the problem!

The best (and most secure) implementation for this is described by Stuart Sharpe in his blog: http://initwithstyle.net/2014/02/making-more-of-the-more-view/

Answer (score 0):

Whatever view is being selected will receive `viewWillAppear:animated:`

Provide this in every view that's controlled by your tab bar, and you can thus extract the identity of the user's selection even when made from a "More" controller.

You can save the tab bar state right in this method, or you can provide your views with a reference back to the tab bar and notify *it*.